# Inequality. $(n+1)!<=n^n$

Tags: inequality, induction

In preparation for the next sem. I am working on an old problem set, ahead of class...

Proof by induction....
This should be true for all $n \geqslant 3$

$$(n+1)! \leqslant n^n$$

I am quite new to doing proofs, and have never done a proof by induction

So I have to basically show that 
$$(n+2)! \leqslant (n+1)^{(n+1)}$$
By assuming that the first equation is true.

There is a comment saying that we should use the inequality of the arithmetic and geometric mean.

But no matter how hard I try i come nowhere close to either of the two expressions.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base case: $n = 3$. Indeed, $4! = 24 \le 3^3 = 27$.

Suppose it is true for $k \ge 3$. Then we find:

$$(k + 2)! = (k + 2)(k + 1)! \le (k + 2) k^k = (k + 2) \cdot k \cdot k^{k - 1} \le (k + 1)^2 k^{k - 1} \le (k + 1)^2 (k + 1)^{k - 1} = (k + 1)^{k + 1}$$

Comment: How do you get from (k+1)^(k+1) to (k+2)k^k

Comment: @Petra I don't understand your question. What specific step are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry I don’t get why you write (k+2)k^k, where did this come from....in the first step it is k^k shouldn’t it then be (k+1)^(k+1) in the next step

Comment: @Petra Well, since we assumed it is true for $k$, we know that $(k + 1)! \le k^k$. We thus find that $(k + 2) (k + 1)! \le (k + 2) k^k$.

Comment: sorry for asking, i get that step now i just have never seen an induction done „the other way round“ ...whatever.... many thanks kind of "funny" to work with inequalities for the first time....